# HAProxy balance b/w multiple backends is not working

Tags: haproxy

My haproxy configuration is as below:

```
defaults
  log global
  mode http
  timeout connect 5000ms
  timeout client 50000ms
  timeout server 50000ms
  timeout queue 50000ms
  timeout http-request 60000ms
  timeout http-keep-alive 5000ms
  max-keep-alive-queue 10
  option httplog
  option redispatch
  option forwardfor
  option http-server-close

frontend front
  bind *:80
  acl use_bar nbsrv(foo) -m int lt 1
  use_backend bar if use_bar
  default_backend foo

backend foo
  server foo1 10.0.0.1:80 check

backend bar
  server bar1 10.0.1.1:80 check
  server bar2 10.0.1.2:80 check
```

My issue is if the `backend foo` is down then the first request to the proxy fails with 503 Service Unavailable.

The subsequent calls work as they get proxied to the `backend bar`.

In no situation, we will like the API call to fail.

Comment: I fixed it by having a single backend using the servers as backup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by keeping a single backend and using servers as backup:

```
defaults
  log global
  mode http
  timeout connect 5000ms
  timeout client 50000ms
  timeout server 50000ms
  timeout queue 50000ms
  timeout http-request 60000ms
  timeout http-keep-alive 5000ms
  max-keep-alive-queue 10
  option httplog
  option redispatch
  option forwardfor
  option http-server-close

frontend front
  bind *:80
  default_backend foo

backend foo
  server foo1 10.0.0.1:80 check
  server bar1 10.0.1.1:80 check backup
  server bar2 10.0.1.2:80 check backup
```